# AWS CLI Create Default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've got an OLD AWS account that apparently does NOT have a default VPC:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-names webserviced --region us-west-1

A client error (VPCIdNotSpecified) occurred when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: No default VPC for this user
```

There's no switch on create-vpc...only a boolean (IsDefault) in the output. I'm trying to replicate my infrastructure to the east coast and this is blocking me :( I don't have ANYTHING created on the east-coast (except for a single VPC that apparently isn't set as the default) so I'd at least like to figure out how to do it there so I don't have these issues in the future.

**How can I define a default VPC?**

P.S. Please don't say that I can't because there's already one defined...unless there's something I'm missing in which case I'd expect a big explanation :)

Comment: Can you please check in one of the regions that you have never before launched instance in, there should probably be default VPC there (I never had a chance to check this :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that it's not possible to set a custom VPC to your default VPC. Most use-cases don't require a lot of customization on a VPC since you can map the network in/out of the tunnel.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mark an existing VPC as a default VPC. You have to contact AWS support to mark your created VPC as the default VPC.

You must provide the following details: your AWS account ID, the region, and the subnet ID. To ensure that your new default subnet behaves as expected, modify the subnet attribute to assign public IP addresses to instances that are launched in that subnet.

Comment: I opened up a case with AWS support. Hopefully this will be resolved quickly. If it is I'll update here.

Comment: AWS cannot mark a previously created VPC as the default VPC. I've talked to multiple agents and got this same answer.

Comment: I don't know who you talked with but read this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/deleted-default-vpc/ @user3063045

Comment: Not sure if you read that link but all it says is that they can create a NEW default VPC for you...nothing about setting an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can [create](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc) a New Default VPC using AWS Console or CLI.